# how to return a list of tables parallel processing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm trying to see how I can return a list of four tables via my parallel loop. Currently, I have a function `calculatef1(k,i)` which returns a vector of four elements `c(score1,score2,score3,score4)`.

```
aggregate_scores <-
  foreach(k = 1:num_metrics, .combine='cbind') %:% 
  foreach(i = 1:10, .combine='c') %dopar% {
    x = c("boot","dtw","sqldf")
    lapply(x, require, character.only=T)
    f1 <- NA
    try(f1<-calculatef1(k,i),silent=TRUE)
    f1
  }
```

Right now, this parallel loop returns a table of 40 rows and `num_metrics` columns, but how would I change my foreach loops so I return a list of 4 tables, each corresponding to a different score, instead (or at least something similar)?

Thanks!

*For reproducibility, use this for the calculatef1 function...

```
calculatef1 <- function(k,i){
  score1 <- k+i
  score2 <- k-i
  score3 <- k*i
  score4 <- k^i 
  c(score1,score2,score3,score4)
}
```

I would like to return a list of four data frames where, for example, the 3rd data frame has score3 for the following pairs of k,i.

```
1*1=1    2*1=2    3*1=3 ...
1*2=2    2*2=4    3*2=6 ...
1*3=3    2*3=6    3*3=9 ...
.        .        .
.        .        .
```

And similarly the 4th data frame would have 1^1, 2^1, 3^1, 1^2, 2^2, and etc. You get the idea.

Comment: It would be best if you provided a reproducible example.

Comment: Just added some more stuff for reproducibility.

Comment: What is the purpose of importing those libraries? I assume they are related to the real calculatef1. Also you should provide a desired output as well. What should the table include? Because as far as I can see, the first loop outputs a 1D array

Comment: Disregard the libraries. I changed my calculatef1 code in here to avoid showing company data.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the trick is to create the appropriate combine functions. You could combine the vectors from the inner `foreach` loop with `rbind` so it returns matrices which are then processed by the outer `foreach` loop. The combine for the outer `foreach` loop could be:

```
comb <- function(x, ...) {
  lapply(1:4, function(i) c(x[[i]], lapply(list(...), function(y) y[,i])))
}
```

This returns a list of four lists, which can be converted into a list of four data frames using a "final" function:

```
final <- function(x) {
  lapply(x, function(y) {
    attr(y, 'names') <- paste('X', seq_along(y), sep='.')
    attr(y, 'row.names') <- .set_row_names(length(y[[1]]))
    class(y) <- 'data.frame'
    y
  })
}
```

You can test these two functions using:

```
x <- list(list(), list(), list(), list())
x <- comb(x, matrix(1, 10, 4), matrix(2, 10, 4))
x <- comb(x, matrix(3, 10, 4), matrix(4, 10, 4))
print(final(x))
```

Finally, you can test them in an actual `foreach` loop:

```
x <- list(list(), list(), list(), list())
aggregate_scores <-
  foreach(k = 1:6, .init=x, .final=final,
          .combine=comb, .multicombine=TRUE) %:%
    foreach(i = 1:10, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
      c(k+i, k-i, k*i, k^i)
    }
```